# Magnetize pen on custom grid

Tags: grid, photoshop, pen

Hello,

I'm doing an illustration in pixel art mode.
I would like to be able to magnetize my pen tool on a custom grid.

I made a grid that cuts my image in 10px increments. But I can't make my 10px pen follow the grid.

Here's what I got: 
[image: Here's what I got]

Here's what I would like: 
[image: Here's what I would like:]
Is it possible to get this under Photoshop?

I tried to find out if anyone had ever wanted to do this but I didn't find any posts on it. If someone could tell me how to solve my problem.

Thank you.

PS: I'm on Photoshop CC 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by disabling the spacing
It doesn't magnetize on the exact square but on the intersection but it's enough.

[image]